# Cómo puedo definir un MIMETYPE al momento de crear un archivo en memoria externa en Android?

Tags: java, android, json

En mi aplicación se interactúa con una API REST con contenidos JSON, dentro de las respuestas dadas por el servidor hay cierta información que almaceno de forma local en el dispositivo usando `getExternalFilesDir()` y un `FileOutputStream()`, al momento de almacenar la información que quiero utilizo una extensión personalizada.

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es enviar mediante un **Intent** la Uri a uno de esos archivos a una aplicación externa que acepta archivos JSON para que sea dicha aplicación quien procese el archivo.

La creación del archivo es correcta, he revisado el contenido del archivo y coincide con las estructuras aceptadas por la otra aplicación, ya probé abrir directamente desde la otra aplicación esos archivos y todo perfecto.

Pero al momento de pasar la Uri del archivo hacia la otra aplicación mediante un `putData()` en un Intent explícito, la aplicación no reconoce el MIMETYPE de los archivos, solo si les cambio la extensión a .json funciona.

Hay alguna forma de establecer los MIMETYPE al momento de crear y escribir en los archivos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que deseas aplicar incorrectamente el uso del MIME TYPE en este caso, por ejemplo imagina que tienes un archivo .mp3 pero cambias la extensión a .pdf, cuando realices el intent para tratar de abrir este archivo que tu sabes es en realidad un .mp3, el intent se realizará pero la aplicación para manipular este tipo de archivos probablemente tendrá problema en reproducir un archivo con extensión .pdf ya que el programa determina el tipo de archivo por la extensión y no por el contenido (MIME TYPE).

> Hay alguna forma de establecer los MIMETYPE al momento de crear y
>   escribir en los archivos?

El [MIME TYPE](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) describe el tipo de contenido, y en el caso de establecer a un archivo un MIME TYPE no es correcto, ya que como comento la aplicación que abrirá este archivo será la que determinará si puede manipular/abrir/reproducir o no cierto tipo de extensiones.

Comment: Creo que puedo hacer lo que quiero con un ContentProvider pues al momento de guardar el archivo en la carpeta de datos de mi aplicación le puedo establecer la extensión que yo quiera, por ejemplo, miarchivo.blp, luego mediante un Intent tipo SEND puedo establecer el mimetype a application/json, lo que si, entonces primero deberé solicitar al usuario elija donde guardar el archivo pues para que funcione debe guardarlo mediante otra aplicación, de esta forma se establece correctamente el mimetype sin importar la extensión, al menos para los JSON...

Comment: @ParisN.Salguero Una duda porque crear un archivo .blp y no .json ya que en realidad tendrá el contenido de un .json?

Comment: Porque quería que esta app movil igual fuera consistente con la app de escritorio que también desarrollé, esta usa archivos blp para almacenar datos JSON y quería mantener esta estructura de extensiones porque quiero en un futuro que cualquiera de estas dos aplicaciones puedan leer estos archivos, además requiero una estructura muy específica dentro de los json. Se que es algo complicado y complejo pero es algo similar a lo que pasa por ejemplo con los archivos de comic's que tienen una extensión especial para identificarlos como tal aunque su mimetype real es ZIP